# html/css cannot stop custom tag from starting new line

Tags: html, css

I've made a floating ad tag in css:

CSS CODE---

```
floatads {
    left:0;
    position:fixed;
    text-align:center;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    z-index:10;
    background-color:#666666;
    border:3px #cccccc dashed;
    font-size:13px;
    color:#ffffff
    }

floatads .license {
    font-size:10px;
    color:#ffffff
    }
```

HTML CODE---

```
<floatads>
<marquee width="70%" scrollamount="5" scrolldelay="20" vspace="5">
Enjoy! | Recommended Website : <a href="http://web-tool.weebly.com">web-tool.weebly.com</a> | Also check out : <a href="http://myzonehk.weebly.com">myzonehk.weebly.com</a> | To register your advertisement and host it here, email <a href="mailto:jamiechoi@mail.com?subject=Host my ad!&body=This is the content of my ad:">jamiechoi@mail.com</a>
</marquee><p class="license">Ads by tool-box.weebly.com</p>
</floatads>
```

But in `<p class="license">`, it jumped to another line.

What can i do to stop it from jumping to another line?

(What i want is:)

> MARQUEE license

license - 10px
MARQUEE - 13px

How can i do this? i just want it to be on the same line.

ADDED------

Also tried this:

(CSS)

```
floatads #license {
    font-size:10px;
    color:#ffffff
}
```

(HTML)

```
<p id="license">ads by tool-box.weebly.com</p>
```

Still not working.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It's not really viable to make up your own HTML elements. Why are you doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use an inline element instead, which saves unnecessary css code.

```
<span id="license">ads by tool-box.weebly.com</span>
```

And one other thing, don't use `marquee` element, as it is non standard. There is other ways using javascript and css animations, that will work cross browser.

Answer (score 1):

Marquee is not a valid HTML element. From MDN:

> **Non-standard** This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards
>   track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not
>   work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between
>   implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

By the way marquee is a block element, so you have to define its width and float it or make it inline. Example:

```
marquee {
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
}
#license {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Or:

```
marquee {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
}
#license {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add display:inline; to the floatads .license

```
floatads .license {
    font-size:10px;
    color:#ffffff;
     display:inline;
    }
```